# Getting error 'This app won't work for your device' on google play store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

A new user of our app is getting the above error on his device (redmi 9a, 2gb ram, 32gb storage). The app is compatible with the device. The device has enough storage & ram available. Couldn't find the solution anywhere. Does anybody know why this issue is occurring. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Tried the following but the issue is not resolved:

- Cleared some storage space.
- Cleared Play Store Cache.
- Updated Play Store.

[image]

Comment: Have you uploaded the app as a apk or a appbundle?

Comment: @Prashant appbundle

Comment: Can you check for minSdkVersion in your build.gradle file and compare it with devices android version

Comment: @Prashant android version is compatible.

Comment: What is minSdkVersion in your build.gradle file?

Comment: minSdkVersion 23 @Prashant

Comment: I've encountered this with some apps on rooted devices. Do you have configured your app to require a device that has not been "tampered" with?